# Were early human beings (about 100 - 200 K years ago) far more promiscuous than we are now?

Tags: sex

I found that many friends of mine are quite easy in sexual relationship. Ex, I knew a lot of girls went to the night club & met a stranger & brought home to sleep  with him even she had never known his name. The next morning, the guy left her & she starts to do the same way to get another guy maybe in 3 days or so.

So that triggered my thought. I wonder "Are early human beings (about 100 - 200 K years ago) far more promiscuous than we are now?"

My hypothesis is "Yes", that is "Early human beings are far more promiscuous than we are now". So how i came up this? Cos Human came from Chimpanzee right?, so if we want to know early human, then we could study Chimpanzee. The early human & Chimpanzee could have some similarities.

There is a research saying that "Chimpanzees are far more promiscuous than humans" http://www.nature.com/news/specials/chimpgenome/interactive/chimp_interactive_graphic_pf.html

So, that proved my hypothesis.

Also, when human evolved, they started to realized that promiscuousness wss not healthy & not good for society so they started to develop some regional/society (ex,  monogamous relationship) codes to prevent that.

Do you approve my hypothesis?

Comment: i'd be surprised if there weren't some time when sex was not socially regulated in the way it was and then the typical human would have more partners than they do on the average (though modernity has definitely increased the maximum number of partners someone can have).  people did not live very long though and sizes of human groups were small on the other hand..

Comment: Your question is interesting but I just want to make some comments about basic stuff that sounds weird in your question. The article you found is not a prove neither an [evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_evidence) for your hypothesis. But it is an interesting fact that should be considered in the discussion. Humans does come from chimpanzee but they both share a common ancestor. If you observe two different phenotypic trait in two sister lineages you cannot quite know which of the two trait had the common ancestor.

Answer (score 2):

> My hypothesis is "Yes", that is "Early human beings are far more
>   promiscuous than we are now". So how i came up this? Cos Human came
>   from Chimpanzee right?

No.

> Also, when human evolved, they started to realized that
>   promiscuousness wss not healthy & not good for society

I'm sorry, what ancient society are you claiming cracked down on **male** promiscuity?

Comment: 1. I guess you meant that chimps are not human ancestors, because the claim regarding human promiscuity is much harder to disprove. 2. Jewish?

Answer (score -2):

Well, your logic is flawed because it is not proven that humans evolved from chimpanzees. not trying to start another debate with the whole evolution, but even if I did believe in evolution I would suggest before making up your hypothesis of researching a lot more than monkeys. Research things like: ancient brothels, traditional marriage views/ cohabitation views, {things that humans practiced and accepted back in the day} and you will have much more evidence.

Comment: Humans did not evolve from chimpanzees. Both evolved from a common ancestor some 5 Mio years ago (which is an important difference).

Comment: even if I did believe in evolution?? So you don't now??